# How can I access elements of an array of hashes in a view? (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm quite new in web development and I am practicing with Sinatra. I am trying to access each element of each hash that is kept inside an array. I googled around and I did not find a clear answer/reason to why I cannot do that in the way I am doing it. Could you please help me with it? Thanks.

what is inside my files:

> app.rb

```
 get '/' do
   @jobs = [{"jobId"=>25347483, "employerId"=>382326},
            {"jobId"=>34543, "employerId"=>3233},
            {"jobId"=>90009, "employerId"=>94949},
            {"jobId"=>5005004, "employerId"=>95959}
           ]
 end
```

> index.erb

```
<body>
  <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <p><%= job['jobId'] %></p>
  <% end %>
</body>
```

error that I get:

> NoMethodError at /
>   undefined method `bytesize' for {"jobId"=>25347483, "employerId"=>382326}:Hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting an error because I couldn't do that! 
As from: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

"Return Values
The return value of a route block determines at least the response body passed on to the HTTP client, or at least the next middleware in the Rack stack. Most commonly, this is a string, as in the above examples. But other values are also accepted.

You can return any object that would either be a valid Rack response, Rack body object or HTTP status code:

An Array with three elements: [status (Fixnum), headers (Hash), response body (responds to #each)]
An Array with two elements: [status (Fixnum), response body (responds to #each)]
An object that responds to #each and passes nothing but strings to the given block
A Fixnum representing the status code"